# Get React + JSX working on Google Cloud Functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, google-cloud-functions, babeljs

Having difficulty getting a hello world react server-side rendering working on Google Cloud Functions. It boils down to two files:

- index.js
- package.json

```js
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/server'

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <h1>Hello!</h1>
  }
}

/**
 * Responds to any HTTP request.
 *
 * @param {!express:Request} req HTTP request context.
 * @param {!express:Response} res HTTP response context.
 */
exports.helloWorld = (req, res) => {
  const html = ReactDOM.renderToString(<App />)
  res.status(200).send(html)
};
```

```
{
  "name": "my.project",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/datastore": "^4.0.0",
    "@google-cloud/storage": "^2.5.0",
    "react": "^16.7.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.7.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "*",
    "@babel/core": "*",
    "@babel/preset-env": "*",
    "babel-loader": "*"
  }
}
```

When I deploy this in the google console from the browser, it errors saying only "Unknown resource type".

Wondering how I get this basic hello world example of React with JSX working on Google Cloud Functions.

Comment: Where do you exec your helloWorld?

Comment: It's in the console by default.

Comment: So you have a router which link the server and the browser?

Comment: I am just trying to get it to compile. I visit the test url in google console to show the output. It works if I don't use any JSX.